# XeLaTeX, nohyphen, space and babel/polyglossia

Tags: xetex, babel, polyglossia, french

Consider this MWE

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{hyphenat}


\begin{document}
\section{without relax}
Cambridge : University (A)

\nohyphens{Cambridge} : University (B)

\texttt{Cambridge} : University (C)

\verb|Cambridge| : University (D)


\section{with relax}

Cambridge\relax : University (E)

\nohyphens{Cambridge}\relax : University (F)

\texttt{Cambridge}\relax : University (G)

\verb|Cambridge|\relax : University (H)
\end{document}
```

If we run it with pdfLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, all the colon are well aligned.

But if we run it with XeLaTeX, it seems that there some spurious spaces (section 1), which can be cancelled with `relax`. Why did we get this behavior? If we don't load babel or polyglossia, the output is also ok.

Any idea?

Comment: For context: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/979

Comment: You shouldn't add a space before the : in the input. Type simply `Cambridge:`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer But the space is supposed to be valid, and `french` uses XeTeX interchars to remove it. I've traced the code and I don't understand why `\ifdim\lastskip >1sp` returns false when executed at the colon in those 2 cases.

Comment: historically, inded, the space is supposed to be valid.

Comment: That's interesting: `{\language\l@french Cambridge} : University` works, but `{\language\l@english Cambridge} : University` doesn't. A bug in XeTeX?

Comment: @JavierBezos ah sorry, I was distracted. I see the problem now.

Comment: @JavierBezos in the second case there is a `\setlanguage28 (hyphenmin 2,3)` between both, and this imho hides the first space.

Comment: @moewe I don't think that anything can be done here. There is a language switch and it prevents xelatex to see the previous space. One can easily see it with showoutput.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That is disappointing. Still, would you like to write up an answer, so this can be resolved? A short explanation of what happens would be great. Is there an alternative to suppressing hyphenation that does not have this side effect? (`biblatex` used to use `\lefthyphenmin\@m`, but that didn't quite work: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/772.)

Comment: I think the `french` option is the main problem. If you run `\verb|Cambridge| :` without  `french` option (and `babel` also) it returns `Cambridge :` and with `french` option it returns `Cambridge:` . doesn't matter `XeLaTex` or  `PdfLaTex` . This also happens for `\texttt{Cambridge} :` and `\texttt{Cambridge}:`.

Comment: @C.F.G Yes-ish. This question is specifically about resolving the issue when `french` is active. (Since in French colons are typeset with an additional space in front, the French localisation module needs to change the behaviour of `:`.)

Comment: indeed. As french people, I want to have my space beform my colon :)

Answer (score 3):

It looks as if one can get around the problem for `\nohyphens` by inserting a zero width space (but I didn't test with many fonts):

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{hyphenat}

\begin{document}

Cambridge : University (A)

\nohyphens{Cambridge} : University (B)

\nohyphens{Cambridge}: University (C)

\renewcommand{\nohyphens}[1]{{{\language\langwohyphens #1}^^^^200b}}

Cambridge : University (A)

\nohyphens{Cambridge} : University (B)

\nohyphens{Cambridge}: University (C)
\end{document}
```

[image]

A similar trick works for `\verb`:

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
Cambridge : University (A)

\verb|Cambridge| : University (C)

\makeatletter
\def\verb@egroup{\global\let\verb@balance@group\@empty\egroup^^^^200d}
\makeatother

Cambridge : University (A)

\verb|Cambridge| : University (C)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice trick. I still think it's a bug in XeTeX, which is inserting the language switch at the wrong place.

Comment: @JavierBezos  It looks as if it is waiting for the next glyph.

Comment: Thank you for the workaround. That's more than I hoped for. You mention not having tested this with many fonts, but is this something that would be font dependent (if the font doesn't have `U+200B` or a non-zero-width `U+200B`)? Fortunately, the zero-width space didn't show up when the text copy-and-pasted (at least in my tests), but it is a bit annoying to have to deal with XeLaTeX separately (the fix won't be acceptable for pdfTeX).

Comment: @moewe I'm not sure if not some .notdef char can appear if the font doesn't have the glyph.

Comment: I see. One would hope that a font designer would put it in, it doesn't seem to be be terribly time consuming to create that glyph. Is there a quick way to test if the glyph exists in the current font?

Comment: @moewe one could test it, but e.g. lm-modern doesn't have it, and tex gyre heros neither, but it doesn't show up, but they don't show a .notdef in other case either, so I'm still not sure if harfbuzz would handle this.

Comment: I'm beginning to get a bit paranoid with this. The outer pair of braces in `\renewcommand{\nohyphens}[1]{{{\language\langwohyphens #1}^^^^200b}}` is not necessary, is it? In my tests `\renewcommand{\nohyphens}[1]{{\language\langwohyphens #1}^^^^200b}` seemed to work just as well, but I want to be sure I'm not missing anything.

Comment: @moewe I think the braces are only there because I tested if additional groups change something.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a comment. I am not a French TeX user, and I don't know which is preferred in writing:  `a thin space before colon :` or `without thin space before colon:`. Just compare by the following pictures that are outputs of the following with different options (with/out `\FBsetspaces{colon}{0.5}{0}{0}`):

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{hyphenat}

\FBsetspaces{colon}{0.5}{0}{0}


\begin{document}
\section{all without relax}
Cambridge : University (A)

\nohyphens{Cambridge} : University (B)

\texttt{Cambridge} : University (C)

\verb|Cambridge| : University (D)


\section{all with relax}

Cambridge\relax : University (E)

\nohyphens{Cambridge}\relax : University (F)

\texttt{Cambridge}\relax : University (G)

\verb|Cambridge|\relax : University (H)

\section{with relax just for typewriter and verbatim}

Cambridge : University (E)

\nohyphens{Cambridge} : University (F)

\texttt{Cambridge}\relax : University (G)

\verb|Cambridge|\relax : University (H)

\section{all without manual space}

Cambridge: University (E)

\nohyphens{Cambridge}: University (F)

\texttt{Cambridge}: University (G)

\verb|Cambridge|: University (H)
\end{document}
```

---

- `PDFLaTeX` with `\FBsetspaces{colon}{0.5}{0}{0}`
  [image]
- `XeLaTeX` with `\FBsetspaces{colon}{0.5}{0}{0}`
  [image]
- `PDFLaTeX` without `\FBsetspaces{colon}{0.5}{0}{0}`
  [image]
- `XeLaTeX` without `\FBsetspaces{colon}{0.5}{0}{0}`
  [image]

Comment: The underlying issue is the same whether we want a thin space with `\FBsetspaces{colon}{0.5}{0}{0}` or take the default normal space. So I don't think this addresses the underlying issue.

Comment: I think the author of package knows about this problem and s/he defined this command. Anyway for more details read [french-babel](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/babel-contrib/french/frenchb-doc.pdf).

Comment: But if you compare the XeLaTeX example with `\FBsetspaces{colon}{0.5}{0}{0}` and without, the only difference is that the excess space is smaller. It is still there (lines B and D). The question was specifically about getting rid of the excess space in lines B and D compared to lines A and C (the input is analogous, yet the output is different).