XeLaTeX+polyglossia+french+biblatex complain about missing character (U+200B)
Note to inattentive users: please stop asking if Unicode char {U+200B} answers my question.
When using biblatex with XeLaTeX and polyglossia-french, I get the following error which seems to come from typesetting the author name in small caps:
Missing character: There is no ​ (U+200B) in font [lmromancaps10-regular]:mapping=tex-text;!

The PDF output is fine, the error is only in the log.
Here is a MWE:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=verbose]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{mmm}

\printbibliography

\end{document}

Here is references.bib:
@Misc{mmm,
  author = {Aaa}
}

What is going on?
If I comment out \setdefaultlanguage{french}, the error goes away, apparently because the author name is no longer typeset in small caps.
I can reproduce the error using TeX Live on Linux Mint 21.3 and on LMDE 6.
Here is test.log:
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=xelatex 2024.3.15)  9 JUN 2024 17:18
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**test.tex
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-01-21>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count181
\c@section=\count182
\c@subsection=\count183
\c@subsubsection=\count184
\c@paragraph=\count185
\c@subparagraph=\count186
\c@figure=\count187
\c@table=\count188
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/polyglossia.sty
Package: polyglossia 2021/04/12 v1.53 Modern multilingual typesetting with XeLa
TeX and LuaLaTeX

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count189
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/makecmds/makecmds.sty
Package: makecmds 2009/09/03 v1.0a extra command making commands
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2020/11/20 v2.8 package option processing (HA)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks16
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks17

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))
\XKV@depth=\count190
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2022-01-21 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def
File: l3backend-xetex.def 2022-01-12 L3 backend support: XeTeX

(|extractbb --version)
\c__kernel_sys_dvipdfmx_version_int=\count191
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count192
\g__color_backend_stack_int=\count193
\g__graphics_track_int=\count194
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box50
\g__pdf_backend_object_int=\count195
\g__pdf_backend_annotation_int=\count196
\g__pdf_backend_link_int=\count197
))
Package: xparse 2022-01-12 L3 Experimental document command parser
)
Package: fontspec 2022/01/15 v2.8a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
Package: fontspec-xetex 2022/01/15 v2.8a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTe
X
\l__fontspec_script_int=\count198
\l__fontspec_language_int=\count199
\l__fontspec_strnum_int=\count266
\l__fontspec_tmp_int=\count267
\l__fontspec_tmpa_int=\count268
\l__fontspec_tmpb_int=\count269
\l__fontspec_tmpc_int=\count270
\l__fontspec_em_int=\count271
\l__fontspec_emdef_int=\count272
\l__fontspec_strong_int=\count273
\l__fontspec_strongdef_int=\count274
\l__fontspec_tmpa_dim=\dimen139
\l__fontspec_tmpb_dim=\dimen140
\l__fontspec_tmpc_dim=\dimen141

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2021/04/29 v2.0v Standard LaTeX package
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty
Package: l3keys2e 2022-01-12 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
)

LaTeX hooks Warning: Generic hook 'file/after/tracklang.sty' is deprecated.
(hooks)              Use hook 'file/tracklang.sty/after' instead.


LaTeX hooks Warning: Generic hook 'package/after/bidi' is deprecated.
(hooks)              Use hook 'package/bidi/after' instead.


LaTeX hooks Warning: Generic hook 'package/after/luabidi' is deprecated.
(hooks)              Use hook 'package/luabidi/after' instead.

\xpg@normalclass=\XeTeXcharclass1
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/gloss-latex.ldf
File: gloss-latex.ldf polyglossia: module for default language
The property list \polyglossia@langsetup contains the pairs (without outer
braces):
>  {latex/script}  =>  {latin}
>  {latex/lcscript}  =>  {latin}
>  {latex/scripttag}  =>  {}
>  {latex/language}  =>  {Latex}
>  {latex/langtag}  =>  {ENG}
>  {latex/bcp47}  =>  {}
>  {latex/hyphennames}  =>  {english}
>  {latex/direction}  =>  {LR}
>  {latex/hyphenmins}  =>  {2,3}
>  {latex/frenchspacing}  =>  {false}
>  {latex/indentfirst}  =>  {false}
>  {latex/fontsetup}  =>  {true}
>  {latex/envname}  =>  {latex}
>  {latex/babelname}  =>  {latex}
>  {latex/localnumeral}  =>  {polyglossia@C@localnumeral}
>  {latex/Localnumeral}  =>  {polyglossia@C@localnumeral}.
)
Package polyglossia Info: Default language is latex.
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/gloss-french.ldf
File: gloss-french.ldf polyglossia: module for french
The property list \polyglossia@langsetup contains the pairs (without outer
braces):
>  {latex/script}  =>  {latin}
>  {latex/lcscript}  =>  {latin}
>  {latex/scripttag}  =>  {}
>  {latex/language}  =>  {Latex}
>  {latex/langtag}  =>  {ENG}
>  {latex/bcp47}  =>  {}
>  {latex/hyphennames}  =>  {english}
>  {latex/direction}  =>  {LR}
>  {latex/hyphenmins}  =>  {2,3}
>  {latex/frenchspacing}  =>  {false}
>  {latex/indentfirst}  =>  {false}
>  {latex/fontsetup}  =>  {true}
>  {latex/envname}  =>  {latex}
>  {latex/babelname}  =>  {latex}
>  {latex/localnumeral}  =>  {polyglossia@C@localnumeral}
>  {latex/Localnumeral}  =>  {polyglossia@C@localnumeral}
>  {french/script}  =>  {Latin}
>  {french/lcscript}  =>  {latin}
>  {french/scripttag}  =>  {}
>  {french/language}  =>  {French}
>  {french/langtag}  =>  {FRA}
>  {french/bcp47}  =>  {fr-FR}
>  {french/hyphennames}  =>  {french,francais}
>  {french/direction}  =>  {LR}
>  {french/hyphenmins}  =>  {2,2}
>  {french/frenchspacing}  =>  {true}
>  {french/indentfirst}  =>  {true}
>  {french/fontsetup}  =>  {true}
>  {french/envname}  =>  {french}
>  {french/babelname}  =>  {french}
>  {french/localnumeral}  =>  {polyglossia@C@localnumeral}
>  {french/Localnumeral}  =>  {polyglossia@C@localnumeral}.
\french@openbrackets=\XeTeXcharclass2
\french@closebrackets=\XeTeXcharclass3
\french@questionexclamation=\XeTeXcharclass4
\french@punctthin=\XeTeXcharclass5
\french@punctthick=\XeTeXcharclass6
\french@punctguillstart=\XeTeXcharclass7
\french@punctguillend=\XeTeXcharclass8
Package polyglossia Info: Option: French, variant=french.
)
Package polyglossia Info: Default language is french.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
Package: biblatex 2022/02/02 v3.17 programmable bibliographies (PK/MW)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode not found.
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2020-10-07 v3.14 Key value format for package options (HO)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty
Package: logreq 2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger
\lrq@indent=\count275

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def
File: logreq.def 2010/08/04 v1.0 logreq spec v1.0
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2020/11/24 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip16
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
\c@tabx@nest=\count276
\c@listtotal=\count277
\c@listcount=\count278
\c@liststart=\count279
\c@liststop=\count280
\c@citecount=\count281
\c@citetotal=\count282
\c@multicitecount=\count283
\c@multicitetotal=\count284
\c@instcount=\count285
\c@maxnames=\count286
\c@minnames=\count287
\c@maxitems=\count288
\c@minitems=\count289
\c@citecounter=\count290
\c@maxcitecounter=\count291
\c@savedcitecounter=\count292
\c@uniquelist=\count293
\c@uniquename=\count294
\c@refsection=\count295
\c@refsegment=\count296
\c@maxextratitle=\count297
\c@maxextratitleyear=\count298
\c@maxextraname=\count299
\c@maxextradate=\count300
\c@maxextraalpha=\count301
\c@abbrvpenalty=\count302
\c@highnamepenalty=\count303
\c@lownamepenalty=\count304
\c@maxparens=\count305
\c@parenlevel=\count306
\blx@tempcnta=\count307
\blx@tempcntb=\count308
\blx@tempcntc=\count309
\c@blx@maxsection=\count310
\c@blx@maxsegment@0=\count311
\blx@notetype=\count312
\blx@parenlevel@text=\count313
\blx@parenlevel@foot=\count314
\c@blx@sectionciteorder@0=\count315
\blx@entrysetcounter=\count316
\blx@biblioinstance=\count317
\labelnumberwidth=\skip49
\labelalphawidth=\skip50
\biblabelsep=\skip51
\bibitemsep=\skip52
\bibnamesep=\skip53
\bibinitsep=\skip54
\bibparsep=\skip55
\bibhang=\skip56
\blx@bcfin=\read2
\blx@bcfout=\write3
\blx@langwohyphens=\language18
\c@mincomprange=\count318
\c@maxcomprange=\count319
\c@mincompwidth=\count320
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex default data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'blx-dm.def' found.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.def
File: blx-dm.def 2022/02/02 v3.17 biblatex localization (PK/MW)
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex style data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'verbose.dbx' not found.
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex custom data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex-dm.cfg' not found.
\c@afterword=\count321
\c@savedafterword=\count322
\c@annotator=\count323
\c@savedannotator=\count324
\c@author=\count325
\c@savedauthor=\count326
\c@bookauthor=\count327
\c@savedbookauthor=\count328
\c@commentator=\count329
\c@savedcommentator=\count330
\c@editor=\count331
\c@savededitor=\count332
\c@editora=\count333
\c@savededitora=\count334
\c@editorb=\count335
\c@savededitorb=\count336
\c@editorc=\count337
\c@savededitorc=\count338
\c@foreword=\count339
\c@savedforeword=\count340
\c@holder=\count341
\c@savedholder=\count342
\c@introduction=\count343
\c@savedintroduction=\count344
\c@namea=\count345
\c@savednamea=\count346
\c@nameb=\count347
\c@savednameb=\count348
\c@namec=\count349
\c@savednamec=\count350
\c@translator=\count351
\c@savedtranslator=\count352
\c@shortauthor=\count353
\c@savedshortauthor=\count354
\c@shorteditor=\count355
\c@savedshorteditor=\count356
\c@labelname=\count357
\c@savedlabelname=\count358
\c@institution=\count359
\c@savedinstitution=\count360
\c@lista=\count361
\c@savedlista=\count362
\c@listb=\count363
\c@savedlistb=\count364
\c@listc=\count365
\c@savedlistc=\count366
\c@listd=\count367
\c@savedlistd=\count368
\c@liste=\count369
\c@savedliste=\count370
\c@listf=\count371
\c@savedlistf=\count372
\c@location=\count373
\c@savedlocation=\count374
\c@organization=\count375
\c@savedorganization=\count376
\c@origlocation=\count377
\c@savedoriglocation=\count378
\c@origpublisher=\count379
\c@savedorigpublisher=\count380
\c@publisher=\count381
\c@savedpublisher=\count382
\c@language=\count383
\c@savedlanguage=\count384
\c@origlanguage=\count385
\c@savedoriglanguage=\count386
\c@pageref=\count387
\c@savedpageref=\count388
\shorthandwidth=\skip57
\shortjournalwidth=\skip58
\shortserieswidth=\skip59
\shorttitlewidth=\skip60
\shortauthorwidth=\skip61
\shorteditorwidth=\skip62
\locallabelnumberwidth=\skip63
\locallabelalphawidth=\skip64
\localshorthandwidth=\skip65
\localshortjournalwidth=\skip66
\localshortserieswidth=\skip67
\localshorttitlewidth=\skip68
\localshortauthorwidth=\skip69
\localshorteditorwidth=\skip70
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load enhanced support for Unicode engines...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'blx-unicode.def' found.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-unicode.def)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load compatibility code...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'blx-compat.def' found.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def
File: blx-compat.def 2022/02/02 v3.17 biblatex compatibility (PK/MW)
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load generic definitions...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex.def' found.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def
File: biblatex.def 2022/02/02 v3.17 biblatex compatibility (PK/MW)
\c@textcitecount=\count389
\c@textcitetotal=\count390
\c@textcitemaxnames=\count391
\c@biburlbigbreakpenalty=\count392
\c@biburlbreakpenalty=\count393
\c@biburlnumpenalty=\count394
\c@biburlucpenalty=\count395
\c@biburllcpenalty=\count396
\biburlbigskip=\muskip17
\biburlnumskip=\muskip18
\biburlucskip=\muskip19
\biburllcskip=\muskip20
\c@smartand=\count397
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'verbose'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'verbose.bbx' found.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/verbose.bbx
File: verbose.bbx 2022/02/02 v3.17 biblatex bibliography style (PK/MW)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'authortitle'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'authortitle.bbx' found.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/authortitle.bbx
File: authortitle.bbx 2022/02/02 v3.17 biblatex bibliography style (PK/MW)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'standard'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'standard.bbx' found.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx
File: standard.bbx 2022/02/02 v3.17 biblatex bibliography style (PK/MW)
\c@bbx:relatedcount=\count398
\c@bbx:relatedtotal=\count399
)))
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load citation style 'verbose'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'verbose.cbx' found.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/verbose.cbx
File: verbose.cbx 2022/02/02 v3.17 biblatex citation style (PK/MW)
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\cite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\parencite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\footcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\footcitetext'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\smartcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\textcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\textcites'.
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load configuration file...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex.cfg' found.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg
File: biblatex.cfg 
)
Package biblatex Info: XeTeX detected.
(biblatex)             Assuming input encoding 'utf8'.
Package biblatex Info: Document encoding is UTF8 ....
Package biblatex Info: ... and expl3
(biblatex)             2022-01-21 L3 programming layer (loader) 
(biblatex)             is new enough (at least 2020/04/06),
(biblatex)             setting 'casechanger=expl3'.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-case-expl3.sty
Package: blx-case-expl3 2022/02/02 v3.17 expl3 case changing code for biblatex
))
\@quotelevel=\count400
\@quotereset=\count401

(./test.aux
LaTeX Info: Redefining \rmfamily on input line 5.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \sffamily on input line 5.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ttfamily on input line 5.
)
\openout1 = `test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TS1+cmr on input line 1
0.
 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd
File: ts1cmr.fd 2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.

Package fontspec Info: Adjusting the maths setup (use [no-math] to avoid
(fontspec)             this).

\symlegacymaths=\mathgroup4
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `legacymaths' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/cmr/bx/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \acute on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \grave on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \ddot on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \tilde on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \bar on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \breve on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \check on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \hat on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \dot on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \mathring on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \colon on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Gamma on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Delta on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Theta on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Lambda on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Xi on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Pi on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Sigma on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Upsilon on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Phi on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Psi on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Omega on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \mathdollar on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `operators' on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `normal' on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> TU/lmr/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `bold' on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/lmr/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  TU/lmr/m/n --> TU/lmr/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> TU/lmr/m/it on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/lmr/b/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> TU/lmss/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/lmtt/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  TU/lmr/m/n --> TU/lmr/b/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> TU/lmr/b/it on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> TU/lmss/b/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/lmtt/b/n on input line 10.
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load language 'french'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'french.lbx' found.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/french.lbx
File: french.lbx 2022/02/02 v3.17 biblatex localization (PK/MW)
)
Package biblatex Info: XeTeX detected.
(biblatex)             Assuming input encoding 'utf8'.
Package biblatex Info: Automatic encoding selection.
(biblatex)             Assuming data encoding 'utf8'.
\openout3 = `test.bcf'.

Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliographic data...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'test.bbl' found.
 (./test.bbl)
Package biblatex Info: Reference section=0 on input line 10.
Package biblatex Info: Reference segment=0 on input line 10.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \rmfamily on input line 10.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \sffamily on input line 10.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ttfamily on input line 10.

Missing character: There is no ​ (U+200B) in font [lmromancaps10-regular]:mappi
ng=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ​ (U+200B) in font [lmromancaps10-regular]:mappi
ng=tex-text;!
The property list \polyglossia@langsetup contains the pairs (without outer
braces):
>  {latex/script}  =>  {latin}
>  {latex/lcscript}  =>  {latin}
>  {latex/scripttag}  =>  {}
>  {latex/language}  =>  {Latex}
>  {latex/langtag}  =>  {ENG}
>  {latex/bcp47}  =>  {}
>  {latex/hyphennames}  =>  {english}
>  {latex/direction}  =>  {LR}
>  {latex/hyphenmins}  =>  {2,3}
>  {latex/frenchspacing}  =>  {false}
>  {latex/indentfirst}  =>  {false}
>  {latex/fontsetup}  =>  {true}
>  {latex/envname}  =>  {latex}
>  {latex/babelname}  =>  {latex}
>  {latex/localnumeral}  =>  {polyglossia@C@localnumeral}
>  {latex/Localnumeral}  =>  {polyglossia@C@localnumeral}
>  {french/script}  =>  {Latin}
>  {french/lcscript}  =>  {latin}
>  {french/scripttag}  =>  {}
>  {french/language}  =>  {French}
>  {french/langtag}  =>  {FRA}
>  {french/bcp47}  =>  {fr-FR}
>  {french/hyphennames}  =>  {french,francais}
>  {french/direction}  =>  {LR}
>  {french/hyphenmins}  =>  {2,2}
>  {french/frenchspacing}  =>  {true}
>  {french/indentfirst}  =>  {true}
>  {french/fontsetup}  =>  {true}
>  {french/envname}  =>  {french}
>  {french/babelname}  =>  {french}
>  {french/localnumeral}  =>  {polyglossia@C@localnumeral}
>  {french/Localnumeral}  =>  {polyglossia@C@localnumeral}.
[1

] (./test.aux
LaTeX Info: Redefining \rmfamily on input line 5.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \sffamily on input line 5.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ttfamily on input line 5.
)
Package logreq Info: Writing requests to 'test.run.xml'.
\openout1 = `test.run.xml'.

 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 12104 strings out of 477394
 286004 string characters out of 5843909
 1044442 words of memory out of 5000000
 32666 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 469299 words of font info for 33 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 682 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 87i,5n,91p,737b,4768s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

Output written on test.pdf (1 page).


U+200B is "zero width space", often abbreviated as ZWSP. Any way you could remove this invisible character from the input file?

@Mico, I do not believe to have this character in the input file. And if I comment out \setdefaultlanguage{french}, the error goes away.

U+200B is an invisible character. The fact that the issue "goes away" when you comment out \setdefaultlanguage{french} is not a valid reason for concluding that the invisible character isn't there.

@Mico, normally Vim shows this character if I copy and paste it. And I've typeset the author name Aaa myself.

I tried, without success, to replicate the issue you report having encountered. Maybe there's a difference between what's in your real bib file and what you hand-typed for this online posting?

@Mico, I copied and pasted. I also saved the files in Windows-1250 encoding using some editor.

@Alexey If you start a new project and copy the files here from your question, do you still get this error?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, I've just tried that, the error is there.

Can you switch to lualatex? I don't get the warning with lualatex instead of xelatex

Can you post the log file?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, no errors with LuaLaTeX.

@Alexey That's why I'm suggesting you use lualatex instead :)

You should update you TeX installation...

@UdiFogiel I can reproduce with xelatex from an up-to-date texlive 2024

I can reproduce the problem, both with babel and polyglossia. The problem is the \textnohyphenation command from biblatex.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I think the advice still holds :)

@UdiFogiel yes, but it won't help :)

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, this is a point of view. If the compiler says there are missing characters, how do I know if the output is as expected?

Does this answer your question? Unicode char {U+200B}

@Davislor, No. The question is already mostly answered by the way. I am just still wondering which package causes the problem, if it is going to be fixed, etc.

U+200B is a zero width space that the bib style is somewhat unhelpfully adding adding to solve a different issue.
You can debug by defining the character
\documentclass{article}
\catcode"200B=\active

\def^^^^200b{HERE}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=verbose]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{referencesx.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{mmm}

\printbibliography

\end{document}

which produces

so doing the same but with
\def^^^^200b{}

would produce the desired outcome.

somehow I have the feeling that it is my fault: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/544914/2388

@UlrikeFischer surely that is always true

Indeed, see https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/f9ffa1b79c5e6b0c900228688929589c8ece5ecc/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-unicode.def#L35-L53 and https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/979. Alternative solutions without unhelpful zero-width characters are appreciated.

@moewe \def^^^^200b{blame Ulrike} ?  more seriously, not sure if {\somefontthathasthischaracter^^^^200b} might work? But it would be better not to need a character, possibly raise on xetex list?

@moewe more efficient than switching to a custom font, how about {\tracinglostchars\z@^^^^200b} ?

Thank you. I think I'll try the \tracinglostchars\z@ trick. As for the XeTeX mailing list: I don't really understand enough about this issue and can't even come up with an example that doesn't load any packages.

Now at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/commit/23f654df8f8f51002b686203b559cbe06dbb941c.
